# CentOS 8 vs CentOS 7 End Of Life

Tags: centos

CentOS 8 EOL date is 31st December 2021, whilst CentOS 7 EOL is 30th June 2024.

This seems a very odd situation to me, where a later release is expiring before an earlier release. Can anyone explain this to me?

I cannot be running EOL systems in 2022 and I don't want to migrate my CentOS 8 servers (which run nginx as a reverse proxy) to CentOS stream.

I'm not too enthusiastic about alternatives such as Rocky Linux either. Perhaps it's an unusual step, but would downgrading to CentOS 7 be a better option to buy some time?

Comment: You seem to be aware of CentOS Stream already. What exactly do you need explaining then?

Comment: Why is an earlier release (CentOS 7) going to EOL three years after a later release? Perhaps there's something I've misunderstood? If CentOS 8 is EOL this year, then why not CentOS 7?

Comment: Are you asking us to speculate on RH's reasons? Only they can say why they did it in this harebrained way.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 8 is **not** a clone of RHEL 8, it's now a rolling release, a sort of testbed.

https://centos.org/distro-faq/

https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/centos-stream-building-innovative-future-enterprise-linux

RHEL 8 is currently free for personal use, so you may as well update to it if you don't want to use its other clones which stick to RHEL packages.

Comment: CentOS 8 and CentOS Stream 8 are different thing. Later one is rolling release, first on is not.

Comment: I don't think so it's now is rolling release

Comment: Offical clarification > [CentOS Linux 8 EOL: 2021-12-31
CentOS Stream 8 EOL: 2024-05-31](https://www.centos.org/cl-vs-cs/)

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan There's no CentOS 8 any more, it'd been discontinued, just CentOS 8 Stream.

Comment: CentOS 8 still exists, its EOL is 31st Dec, 2021.

Comment: IOW it'll be dead in 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems a very odd situation to me, where a later release is expiring before an earlier release. Can anyone explain this to me?

CentOS 8 expairing before CentOS 7, as per decision of its governing body from RedHat, in favour of CentOS Stream.

CentOS (2004) was orignially a community project which rebuilt RHEL packages removing RH trademark parts and community supported, a downstream of RHEL. In 2014, RH acquired CentOS trademark and website and started to directly back the project.

- CentOS 8 was released in 2019-09-24. Originally CentOS 8 had full-update upto 2025 and maintainance update upto 2029. It was cut short to 2021-12-31.
- CentOS 7 was released in 2014-07-07. It has full-update upto 2020-08-06 and mainatinance update upto 2024-06-30.

Why the life was cut short because RH released CentOS Stream which is a rolling release distro, which will be updated *prior* to RHEL, essentially its upstream. Not everyone is happy to know that their server OS will be testbed to someone else. [Official statement](https://www.centos.org/cl-vs-cs/), emphasis mine:

> **CentOS Linux** is a rebuild of Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL). As such, it is **downsteam** from RHEL. CentOS Linux release version numbers reflect the date of the RHEL release on which they are based. For example, CentOS 8.2105 is a rebuild of RHEL 8.3, which released in May of 2021.
> **CentOS Stream**, on the other hand, is the **upstream, public development** branch for RHEL. Specifically, CentOS Stream 8 is the upstream for the next minor release of RHEL 8, CentOS Stream 9 for the next minor release of RHEL 9, and so on.

**What's the future ?**

There are three possible replacement for CentOS, all are downstream to RHEL:

- **Rocky Linux** ( June 2021) is a new community-maintained distro which is intended to replace CentOS, leaded by the original developer of CentOS. Rocky Linux 8 is intended to be supported upto 2029. Basically CentOS with new name but not fully-fledged.
- **AlmaLinux** (March 2021) is also started for same intention, maintained by CloudLinux, a company which also has a commercial offering CloudLinux OS. Their FAQ says "CloudLinux is committed to supporting AlmaLinux until 2029".
- **Oracle Linux** (2006), maintained by Oracle, with optional commercial support. It is not intended to replace CentOS, but should work.